# How to select p and q tag in jsoup such that if same element is under the both the tags,it should be selected once?

Tags: css-selectors, jsoup

How to select `p` tag and `b` tag both and if `p` and `b` have same element then only one should be selected.

```
<html>
    <div>
        <p><b>This is first line</b></p>
        <b>This is second line</b>
        <span style="color:blue">This is third line</span>
    </div>
</html>
```

How do I select all the three lines only once?

If I use `html.select("p,b");`, `<p><b>This is first line</b></p>` gets selected twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I select all the three lines only once?

<s>Use the parent with a selector for child nodes `div>*`</s> ([see CSS reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp)):

**Update:** use selector for elements, that are not `<div>` but a have a `<div>` parent `.select("div>:not(div)")`

```
String htmlString = "<html><div><p><b>This is first line</b></p><b>This is second line</b><span style=\"color:blue\">This is third line</span></div></html>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlString);

Elements elements = doc.select("div>:not(div)");

for (Element element : elements) {
    System.out.println(element.toString());
}
```

This prints out:

```
<p><b>This is first line</b></p>
<b>This is second line</b>
<span style="color:blue">This is third line</span>
```

If you will only use the text inside the nodes simply use `element.text()`

Comment: "div>*" did help can you explain why div>* worked and not just "div"

Comment: `div` alone would select the whole `div` element. But we want to select all elements, that have `div` as a parent. For example `div>p` would select all `p` elements with a `div` as parent. Since we have different elements in the `div` we use the wildcard selector `*` (added a link to my answer regarding the CSS selector).

Comment: Thanks alot It reaally helped

Comment: String htmlString = "<html><div><div><div><p><b>This is first line</b></p></div><b>This is second line</b></div><div><span style=\"color:blue\">This is third line</span></div></html>";

             org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc1 = Jsoup.parse(htmlString);

             Elements elements1 = doc1.select("div>*");

             for (Element element : elements1) {
                 System.out.println(element.toString());
             }

Comment: If i change the string htmlString as above it gives output as                        <div>
 <div>
  <p><b>This is first line</b></p>
 </div>
 <b>This is second line</b>
</div>
<div>
 <p><b>This is first line</b></p>
</div>
<p><b>This is first line</b></p>
<b>This is second line</b>
<div>
 <span style="color:blue">This is third line</span>
</div>
<span style="color:blue">This is third line</span> --------------

Comment: For starters: there is a closing </div> tag missing, where is supposed to be?

Comment: I guessed it is missing as closing tag at the end. Updated the selector in my answer, it works for the old and the new structure.

Answer (score 1):

You need the [pseudo-selector](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) `:not` to exclude the child `b` tag.

```
for (Element e : doc.select("p :not(b),b"))
    System.out.println(e.ownText());
```

Output

```
This is first line
This is second line
```

---

To include the third line, add `span` to your selector.

```
for (Element e : doc.select("p :not(b),b,span"))
    System.out.println(e.ownText());
```

Output

```
This is first line
This is second line
This is third line
```