# How to use :empty pseudo selector in jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I want to select the div tag that has no more div or any other tag.
i tried the below code and i want the output as "This is output"
but empty pseudo-selector isn't working.

```
String htmlString = 
"<html><div><div><div><p><b>This is first line</b></p>   </div><b>This is second line</b></div><div>This is output</div><div><span style=\"color:blue\">This is third line</span></div></html>"`;

            org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc1 = Jsoup.parse(htmlString);

            Elements elements1 = doc1.select("html:empty");

            for (Element element : elements1) {
                System.out.println(element.toString());
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you posted a couple of [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38893052/) recently, where your html structure changed and the css selector broke, maybe it would be better/more suiting for you, to avoid the css selectors and process/filter the elements yourself:

```
String htmlString = "<html><p><b>This has no div</b></p><div><div><div><p><b>This is first line</b></p></div><b>This is second line</b></div><div>This is output</div><div><span style=\"color:blue\">This is third line</span></div></html>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlString);

Elements elements = doc.getAllElements();

// for all textnodes
outerloop:
for (Element element : elements) {
    if(element.childNodes().size()>0 && element.childNode(0).nodeName().equals("#text")){
        Element divContent = element;

        if(divContent.nodeName().equals("div")){
            System.out.println("No element in div; text: " + element.text()+ "\n");
        }else{  
            while(divContent.parents().size()>0 && !divContent.parent().nodeName().equals("div")){
                divContent = divContent.parent();
                if(divContent.parent().nodeName().equals("body")){
                    continue outerloop; // continue, to skip element <p><b>This has no div</b></p>
                    //break; // break, if you want the element <p><b>This has no div</b></p> anyway 
                }
            }

            System.out.println("element: " + divContent.toString());
            System.out.println("text: " + element.text() + "\n");
        }
    }
}

// only for <div>text...</div>
for (Element element : elements) {
    if(element.childNodes().size()>0 && element.childNode(0).nodeName().equals("#text") && element.nodeName().equals("div")){
        System.out.println("text: " + element.text());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
element: <p><b>This is first line</b></p>
text: This is first line

element: <b>This is second line</b>
text: This is second line

No element in div; text: This is output

element: <span style="color:blue">This is third line</span>
text: This is third line

text: This is output
```

Comment: Can you please explain this "element.childNodes().size()>0 && element.childNode(0).nodeName().equals("#text")"  inside for loop in If condition

Comment: I check if the element has at least one childnode and if that childnode has a nodename "#text". E.g. `<b>This is first line</b>` would match. Then I find the closest div parent tag, to grab additional tags... Just play around with parent and child nodes and print out the element text and nodenames while comparing to the html source to get a feeling for the usage.

Comment: Cool. This is really good and i guess it will never break. Thanks alot !!

Comment: Well, parsing/scraping is always dependent on the source structure. Since you initially requested all additional tags except `<div>` the current version would skip text that is not enclosed  by a `<div>`. If you were just after the inner text it would be really stable and simpler: for (Element element : elements) {
if(element.childNodes().size()>0 && element.childNode(0).nodeName().equals("#text")){System.out.println(element.text());}
}

Comment: I added a non `<div>` enclosed case, check the while condition for the handling (either break the while or continue the outer loop).

Answer (score 0):

I tried this it working

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String htmlString =
                "<html>" +
                        "<div><div>" +
                        "<div><p><b>This is first line</b></p>   </div>" +
                        "<b>This is second line</b></div><div>This is output</div>" +
                        "<div><span style=\"color:blue\">This is third line</span></div></html>";

        org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc1 = Jsoup.parse(htmlString);

        for (Element e : doc1.select("div:not(b),div:not(p),div:not(span)"))
            System.out.println(e.ownText());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
This is output
```